# Cordova plugin developement

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, cordova

I currently try developing plugins for cordova. I Already got a simple "echo" plugin working and could install it automatically through `cordova plugin install LOCAL_PATH`.

Now I want to edit my plugin (specific the .js file) after installation. I read that I have to change the original .js file, because it´s deployed to platform specific folder when executing "cordova prepare". But the .js file in android/assets doesn´t change. When I edit this file direktly it is replaced after "cordova prepare", even when the original .js file does not exists any more.

This is my plugin.xml

```
...
<asset src="www/myEcho.js" target="js/myEcho.js" />

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="MyEcho">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.example.myplugin.MyEcho"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/MyEcho.java" target-dir="src/com/example/myplugin" />
</platform>
...
```

Thanks in advance

P.S.:
According to the documentation the "asset" tag should cause that the myEcho.js file is copied to the top level www folder. That does not happen (but it is copied to the platform specific www folder). Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the "www/MyEcho.js" file in the LOCAL_PATH folder and re-add it to the app with  "cordova plugin install LOCAL_PATH".

Comment: But I think it is not the best way. Because when I use plugin from cordova, I am able to change them and apply the changes with 'cordova prepare'. So I don't have to reinstall them. So I think there is still  a bug in my configuration...